# Atomic read/write for function pointer in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, function-pointers, atomic

I am working on some code in C that is run on Windows as well as other platforms. I know of functions such as InterlockedExchangePointer to atomically read/write a data pointer, and I'm sure there's something similar for other platforms, but how can I do that with a function pointer in a portable way? Is it possible or do I need a lock or a memory barrier or something?

Comment: Is [atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic) an option ?

Answer (score 1):

C11 [atomics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) is the standard-based thing, but not all compilers support it.

GCC 4.1+, as well as compilers like clang and ICC which strive for compatibility with it support [`__sync` builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html).

I have [some code](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/tree/master/atomic) which provides a common API that you might be interested in.